# .vim/: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and trying to install NERD tree plugin for Vim. As specified on all of the guides on installing vim plugins by placing the NERD tree files inside .vim/ directory, I could not find such directory.

```
cd ~/.vim/
bash: cd: /home/tushar/.vim/: No such file or directory
```

If there is any better way to install the plugin then please post the steps.

Comment: Look at [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle), I think that's the easiest and cleanest.

Comment: Thank you @vidit for your quick response. I did exact what is said on the Readme of the file. I completed the Step no. 1 from quick start but could not understand the second step (Configure Bundles:  Sample .vimrc). Could you please elaborate the step.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada, don't bother, vundle is not necessary *at all* (so is NERDTree). Learn your basics first.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ cd
$ mkdir .vim
$ cd .vim
$ (do your thing)
```